# Why doesn't my model show up in a separate 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view

I haven't done anything too weird to this model. I set the unit of measurement for the scene to mm and that's about it. It's about 100mm wide. In the default window I can still see the model. But when I open another view to get a second perspective it's empty. Sorry for the vague question but I don't know how to describe what's happening here other than  "it's not there".

[image]

Comment: Please try selecting it in the window where you see it, then go to the other window and press ".". Do you still not see it? If you don't it can be a camera settings issue.

Comment: select > other window > . > nada > oh god why? why me!?

Comment: Bring out properties, try view/clip/start and input lower value an please report afterwards :)

Comment: same thing (nothing)

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: Remember in bottom 3d view you are in local view. The cursor and green y axis are in same place above and below, your view axes shown bottom left are same, meaning your object is out of view and obscured to the right. As pointed out by previous comment put cursor over view, press numpad  "."  to focus object.

Comment: It's strange because the upper window shows that there is nothing on any of the layers. I can't find out how this is possible.

Comment: I might be missing something because period (or numpad .) isn't working for me. Here's the file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qe2v4d3vxT032LFpc6OJaHjGgmpm8uvn

Comment: @user875234 Press / (above NumPad) to exit from Local View

Comment: lol nope, I'm starting to worry this is going to be something totally obvious and I'm going to look like an idiot.

Comment: @user875234 Not nope, I have tested it and it solves the issue. Just exit from Local View in the bottom window (check your shortcuts, maybe you have a different one for Local View - press SpaceBar and type Local View).

Comment: @user875234 Then I suggest to enlarge your Clipping settings, you have it restricted to 1 meter, it will be difficult to work with this settings.

Comment: @JanKadeřábek okay, yep that was it! (I wan't pressing / on the numpad). Seriously, thanks!

Comment: @user875234 Glad to help, happy Blending! :)